# Days passed since creation of the cell

Tags: ios, swift

I've managed to create the first phase of my first app in iOS so bear with me.

The app looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The idea of the app is to have a number on the right side of the cell, counting the days since the creation of said cell, so I can keep track of how many days have passed since I've done something.

A cell should look like this:

```
Went jogging             5
```

This would mean I went jogging (created the cell) 5 days ago.

I'm using CoreData and added a Date property to the Items, don't know if that's useful or not.

1) How can I put the number of days on the right side of the cell?

2) How can make the counter start when creating the cell? (I assume this goes in the `addButtonPressed` method)

`addButtonPressed` method:

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var textField = UITextField()
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Item", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add New Item", style: .default) { (action) in

        let newItem = Item(context: self.context)
        newItem.title = textField.text!

        newItem.parentCategory = self.selectedCategory
        self.itemArray.append(newItem)
        self.saveItems()
    }

    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Create New Item"
        textField = alertTextField
    }

    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: 1. create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. Ideall add the label to a xib, add right constraint, connect to outlet. 2. Save the creation date to your database, when the cell is displayed, start a timer that will update your label every about 100ms, giving a new text that depends on current time and the creation date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write code since it does not seem that you need programming help, you need contextual help. Here is how you can go about doing that.

1: Subclass UITableViewCell and create your own cell with a custom label that shows the number of days.

2: Create an array to store creation time dates

3: Upon app close, use `UserDefaults` to store the new array. You could do this by removing the old initial array (if the user added some new cells, your array would grow) or you can just update the old array.

4: Assuming your person doesn't have the app open longer than an hour, you can just check upon open of your app, currentTime - initialTime would provide you a new time, and you can obtain the amount of days passed. If you really want, could add a timer every 5-10 minutes to check. If you want every minute, I'd recommend a timer every 30sec to update, or something like that. Save where you can in terms of computation.

5: You'd also need to save an array of the items "Test, Test 2, Test 3" in `UserDefaults` so you can reload them.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned that he uses CoreData to store his information. Also you could improve your answer by providing relevant links to documentation.

Comment: Sure, he uses CoreData. It didn't state it was required. I find examples like this to be more opt to utilize `UserDefaults`.